# Elastic collision question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision

I have a simple elastic collision question.

In a perfectly elastic collision between equal masses, can the mass with a slower speed transfer energy to the mass with a faster speed?

No constraints are placed on the initial directions the balls are traveling along, or on the orientation of the plane of contact. The question is asking for the amount of energy that can possibly be transferred from the slower mass to the faster mass in an elastic collision.

Comment: The balls are of equal mass, so their momentum is just going to swap. Total energy transfer is the difference in kinetic energy when hit head on.

Comment: That's only if the balls are traveling along the same line and have a head-on collision.  In that case the slower ball receives energy from the faster ball. This question is asking if the faster ball can receive energy from the slower ball and how much is possible.

Comment: You can't transfer any, the energy can only go down.

Comment: @looksquirrel101 - you need to work out the different scenarios for the edge cases, in line, head on and perpendicular.

Comment: @ja72 - Yes, I have done that.  I am looking for confirmation.

Comment: @knzhou - The energy of the system remains constant in an elastic collision, however the balls do exchange energy.  The question is asking how much energy can the slower ball transfer to the faster ball.

Comment: I told you none, the energy of the faster ball in your setup can only go down.

Comment: @knzhou - I'm sorry, but that answer is incorrect.  Did you try to solve it or are you just guessing?

Comment: On reflection I think this isn't really homework because it's asking about the principles involved in two body collisions. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @JohnRennie - Thank you. That was the intent, and it is interesting to see that the correct answer has a negative score right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conservation of moment => $m_1$**v**$_1 + m_2$**v**$_2 = m_1$**v**$_1' + m_2$**v**$_2'$.

Conservation of energy => $1/2m_1v_1^2 + 1/2m_2v_2^2 = 1/2m_1v_1'^2 + 1/2m_2v_2'^2$

Masses are the same:

**v**$_1 + $**v**$_2 = $**v**$_1' + $**v**$_2'$
$v_1^2 + v_2^2 = v_1'^2 + v_2'^2$

Squaring the first and subtracting from the second:

**v**$_1.$**v**$_2 = $**v**$_1'.$**v**$_2'$

That means: if the initial velocities are perpendicular, its inner product is zero. In that case, a possible outcome compatible with an elastic collision is **v**$_1'$ or **v**$_2'$ be zero, "transferring" all energy to the other particle.

Comment: Thank you! I agree. The slower ball can transfer all of its energy to the faster ball.

Comment: Please don't provide full solutions to HW&E questions.

Comment: This is not a homework problem. It was a conceptual question designed to show that a low kinetic energy particle can transfer its energy to a high kinetic energy particle. Perhaps it would be a good HW question.

Comment: This isn't correct.  You claim that when the initial velocities are pendular the LHS of the equation is zero (true) therefore the RHS is zero as well (also true) but then make the leap that therefore one of the individual velocities after the collision can be zero - this part is not true.  There are restrictions on the angles/directions of the exit velocities, in fact if the initial are perpendicular then the exit velocities will also be, this making the RHS zero.

Comment: @dllahr - Sorry, but you are mistaken.  You can check for yourself. Take ball 1 to be moving in the x-direction and ball 2 in the y-direction.  One possible final set of velocities is **v**'_1 = 0 and **v**'_2 = 2 **i** + 4 **j**.  The other possible solution with a zero velocity ball is **v**'_2 = 0 and **v**'_1 = 2 **i** + 4 **j**. The first has a contact tangent plane with normal in the x-direction and the second has the tangent plane in the y-direction.

Comment: You're right my mistake.  I thought about in terms of the fact that although ball 1 has higher speed, if you take them to be perpendicular initially (as you describe) ball 1 is slower than ball 2 in that direction.  Thus I can see how ball 2 strikes ball 1 just right transferring all energy; now ball 1 is traveling 2 in x, 1 in y and is faster, ball 2 is slower.

Comment: however @dllahr still the faster ball will lose energy. (see here in the comments: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/525796/conceptual-block-on-energy-transfer/525812?noredirect=1#comment1188334_525812)

Comment: That's not what the above people are saying I would take it up with them not me, they've done much more work and thought about it